# AngularJS (1.x) directive: how to render a local variable in the template, without making it directive tag's attribute?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive in AngularJS (1.x) that should render a local variable into its template. I don't want that variable to be mapped to directive's attributes, though.

```
function myDirective($filter) {
    /**
     * Returns the directive definition object.
     * It is meant to be used as follows:
     *
     * <my-directive></my-directive>
     */
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {local: '&'},
        template: "<div> {{ local }} </div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.local = Math.random();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a variable, called `local`, and its value is not meant to be passed as a directive's attribute, e.g. `<my-directive local=""></my-directive>`. I want it to be just `<my-directive></my-directive>`.

How do I achieve that?

Note: I don't want to use `controllerAs`/`bindToController` syntax so far.

Comment: Well, remove `scope: {local: '&'},`.

Comment: Use the attrs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#attributes

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, so I can just assign a property to scope, without declaring it at all? Thanks, that's the answer I needed!

Comment: I would also recommend using the `controller: func` property over the `link` function.  While the link function does give you access to scope, it's much cleaner to use the controller instead if you don't actually care about the other `element, attr` arguments.